# Python - How to speed up cosine similarity with counting arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, scipy

I need to compute the cosine similarity function across a very big set. This set represents users and each user as an array of object id. An example below:

```
user_1 = [1,4,6,100,3,1]
user_2 = [4,7,8,3,3,2,200,9,100]
```

If my understanding is correct, to compute the cosine similarity I need first to create counting arrays to have a common representation for each of them. Then, I need to compute the cosine similarity function. For counting arrays I mean the following:

```
#user_1 array
#                        1,2,3,4,5,6,[7-99],100,[101-200]
user_1_counting_array = [2,0,1,1,0,1,.......,1,.........]
user_2_counting_array = [0,1,2,1,0,0,1,1,1,.,1,.......,1]
```

(The dots represents zeros in this case)

after I get this common representation I use the cosine similarity function from sklearn.

```
from scipy import spatial
s = 1 - spatial.distance.cosine(user_1_counting_array, user_2_counting_array)
```

The problem is that when I actually run the code, everything is extremely slow, and I have more than 1M of user. I understand that the combination will be a lot, but I think that how I am creating the common representation generate a very big bottleneck.

For completeness, the following represent my implementation:

```
from collections import Counter
from scipy import spatial

def fill_array(array, counter):
    for c in counter:
        array[c] = counter[c]
    return array

user_1 = [1,4,6,100,3,1]
user_2 = [4,7,8,3,3,2,200,9,100]

user_1_c = Counter(user_1)
user_2_c = Counter(user_2)

if max(user_1_c) > max(user_2_c):
    max_a = max(user_1_c)+1
else:
    max_a = max(user_2_c)+1

user_1_c_array = [0]*max_a
user_2_c_array = [0]*max_a

fill_array(user_1_c_array, user_1_c)
fill_array(user_2_c_array, user_2_c)

result = 1 - spatial.distance.cosine(user_1_c_array, user_2_c_array)
```

Comment: I assume you're doing this for graphs, (e.g. friends/connections). In this case, you shouldn't need to use cosine similarity on *all* before a max_index. You only need to use a vector which contains all element that *exist in at least one of the 2 list*.

Comment: You are right, but computationally speaking I have the feeling that creating these vectors requires much more computation. Don't you think so? @RockyLi

Comment: It's actually much less since you're looping over huge amount of empty data. It's also faster when you're using hash (set, dictionary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can get your short and concise cosine similarity vectors without looping over a million entries:

```
user_1 = [1,4,6,100,3,1]
user_2 = [4,7,8,3,3,2,200,9,100]

# Create a list of unique elements
uniq = list(set(user_1 + user_2))

# Map all unique entrees in user_1 and user_2
duniq = {k:0 for k in uniq}

def create_vector(duniq, l):
    dx = duniq.copy()
    dx.update(Counter(l)) # Count the values
    return list(dx.values()) # Return a list

u1 = create_vector(duniq, user_1)
u2 = create_vector(duniq, user_2)

# u1, u2:

u1 = [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
u2 = [0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

You can then feed these 2 vectors into `spatial.distance.cosine`